# How to change text's color and config text's touch action in AlertView?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I want to write a `UIAlertView` like this picture:

[image]

I want to write some effects in it. We call the text"click(have color)" text1, and the text remained is text2. I want to change the text1's color different from text2, and I can write some click Action so that when I click the text1, this Action will be invoked.

I know that `NSAttributeString` can change text's color. But I didn't find which attribute can write the click Action. There's only one attribute that I can open url. But my purpose is push a viewController under a navigation.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to do. The `UIAlertView` is deprecated and you can probably find something you want to do with `UIAlertController` and `UIAlertAction`.

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom `UIViewController`, where you can write everything that you want. Present it modally over current context.

I don't think that tricking `UIAlertController` is a good idea